# ajax & javascript help needed (I need a small amount of code to be replaced)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a script that i need modified.
Currently the script listens for my keyboard input and outputs something that I want.

What I would like it to do instead of placing what I want beforehand directly into the script, the ability to simply make that text =  the text within a .txt document.
so instead of editing the script directly I type in the document and save it.

**example being:**

```
$.ajax("/TEST.txt").success(function (text) {  e = text; next() });
```

**I would like something similar to the above example to replace what I currently have which is below:**

```
var e = { a: "apple", b:"ball"};
```

**full working code is below var e is near the center of the script**

```
javascript: (function () {
    function s(r) {
        var i = r[5];
        if (n && e[i]) {
            var s = w.getTile(r[0], r[1]);
            var a = r[2] * 16 + r[3];
            s._pendingEdits[a].length = 0;
            s.getCell(r[2], r[3]).innerHTML = " ";
            var f = e[i];
            var l = f.split("\n");
            var c = o(l);
            var h = [];
            for (var p = 0; p < l.length; p++) {
                var d = l[p].replace("{b}", "");
                for (var v = 0; v < d.length; v++) {
                    t = Math.max(t, v + 1);
                    var m = u(r, d.charAt(v), v, -c + p + 1);
                    var s = w.getTile(m[0], m[1]);
                    if (!Permissions.can_edit_tile(w.userModel, w.worldModel, s)) continue;
                    s && s.tellEdit(m[2], m[3], m[5], m[4]);
                    var g = s.getCell(m[2], m[3]);
                    g.innerHTML = Helpers.escapeChar(m[5]);
                    h.push(m)
                }
            }
            return h
        } else {
            return [r]
        }
    }

    function o(e) {
        var t = 0;
        for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
            t++;
            if (e[n].indexOf("{b}") >= 0) {
                break
            }
        }
        return t
    }

    function u(e, t, n, r) {
        var i = f(a(e[0], e[2], 8) + r, 8);
        var s = f(a(e[1], e[3], 16) + n, 16);
        return [i[0], s[0], i[1], s[1], e[4] + 10, t]
    }

    function a(e, t, n) {
        return n * e + t
    }

    function f(e, t) {
        return [Math.floor(e / t), ((e < 0 ? t : 0) + e % t) % t]
    }

    function l(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            t = r
        }
        d.call(this, e);
        t = 1
    }

    function h(e, t) {
        c[e] = w[e];
        w[e] = function () {
            w._super = function () {
                c[e].apply(w, arguments)
            };
            t.apply(w, arguments)
        }
    }

    function p(e) {
        if (e.which == 3) {
            console.log("Big Font Turned Off");
            STOP_POST = true;
            $(document).unbind("keydown", l).bind("keydown", d);
            $(window).unbind("mousedown", p);
            for (var t in c) {
                w[t] = c[t]
            }
        }
    }
    var e = {

      a: "apple",
      b:"ball"
    };
    var t = 1,
        n = false,
        r = 1;
    for (var i in e) {
        r = Math.max(r, e[i].split("\n").length)
    }
    var c = {};
    h("typeChar", function (e) {
        n = true;
        var t = this._super(e);
        n = false;
        return t
    });
    h("moveCursor", function (e, n) {
        for (var r = 0; r < t; r++) {
            n = this._super.call(this, e, n)
        }
        t = 1
    });
    h("queueEdit", function (e) {
        var t = s(e);
        for (var n = 0; n < t.length; n++) {
            this._super(t[n])
        }
    });
    h("sendEdits", function () {
        if (!this._edits.length) return;
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.pathname,
                data: {
                    edits: JSON.stringify(this._edits.splice(0, 199))
                },
                success: this.editsDone,
                dataType: "json",
                error: this.editsError
            });
        return this._edits = []
    });
    h("editsDone", function () {
        if (this._edits.length > 0) {
            this.sendEdits()
        }
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments)
    });
    var d = $(document).data("events").keydown[0].handler;
    $(document).unbind("keydown", d);
    $(document).bind("keydown", l);
    $(window).bind("mousedown", p);
    console.log("Big Font Turned On!")
})()
```

Comment: Why in the world are you writing minified code by hand?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, do you want to read the text file and return its contents into the code?

Comment: Wow, you're posting formatted minified code and now ask other people to fix it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You current data seems to be a javascript object, perfectly represented as a json string, so:

```
// Javascript file
var e = "";

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/TEST.json",
  success: function (data) {  
    e = data; 
    next();
  })
});

// TEST.json
{
  "a" : "Text1",
  "b" : "Text2"
}
```

I assume the next() function is used to initialize your script with the e variable, but i supose you could improve this by passing the e variable as an argument of the next function, like `next(e);`.

This means you dont need to initialize `e` outside of the ajax request and prevents namespace polution.

JSON is basically formatted text, so it solves your eventual "what will my data format be" problem at the same time.